# Recebendo POST da API

Tags: php, sql

Estou com problemas em receber dados via POST da API da Cielo.
Já falei com a King Host e está tudo certo em relação aos certificados e etc.

Eu andei pesquisando no GitHub e achei um tópico parecido:
https://github.com/DeveloperCielo/Checkout-Cielo/issues/8

Segui as recomendações porém sem exito, o Banco de Dados não faz o Update.

Estou usando o framework CodeIgniter 3, e pus as páginas de notificação e status na pasta Public

Segue o código das páginas

```
$order_number = $_POST['order_number'];
if(isset($order_number)){
//as variaveis de conexão eu escondi
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host; dbname=$dbname", $userdb, $userpass);
$pdo->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");      // Sets encoding UTF-8
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql = 'UPDATE `tb_store_orders` SET `details_ship` = :details_ship, `order_shipping` = :price_ship, `order_status` = :order_status, `order_tid` = :order_tid WHERE `order_number` = :order_number';

        $mod_ship = $_POST['shipping_type'];
        $name_ship = $_POST['shipping_name'];
        $price_ship = $_POST['shipping_price'];
        $cep_ship = $_POST['shipping_adress_zipcode'];
        $dist_ship = $_POST['shipping_adress_district'];
        $city_ship = $_POST['shipping_adress_city'];
        $state_ship = $_POST['shipping_state'];
        $adre_ship1 = $_POST['shipping_adress_line1'];
        $adre_ship2 = $_POST['shipping_adress_line2'];
        $number_ship = $_POST['shipping_adress_number'];
        $details_ship = $mod_ship.'<br>'.
                        $name_ship.'<br>'.
                        $price_ship.'<br>'.
                        $cep_ship.'<br>'.
                        $state_ship.'<br>'.
                        $city_ship.'<br>'.
                        $adre_ship1.', '.$number_ship.', '.$adre_ship2.', '.$dist_ship;
        $order_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
        $order_tid = $_POST['tid'];

 $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
 $statement->bindValue(":details_ship", $details_ship);
 $statement->bindValue(":price_ship", $price_ship);
 $statement->bindValue(":order_status", $order_status);
 $statement->bindValue(":order_tid", $order_tid);
 $statement->bindValue(":order_number", $order_number);

$count = $statement->execute();
  $pdo = null; 
        echo '<status>OK</status>';
        }
        echo 'Nenhum';
?>
```

Alguém tem alguma sugestão?

Comment: Qual o erro que esta obtendo?

Comment: Aí que está, não tenho como saber. Porque não faz update na tabela. e eu não sei se os parâmetros estão indo para essa página.

Comment: Veja no log do PHP. Adicione `var_dump` para ver valores das variáveis. Utilize phpdebug para analisar o que acontece na execução do script. Veja a requisição gerada pelo browser nas ferramentas de de desenvolvedor se há algum dado anormal. E adicione quaisquer informações que julgue relevantes resultados dessas análises para a sua pergunta. Confira no banco de dados se há uma tupla na tabela sendo modificada com o valor passado em `order_number`.

Comment: Vinícius Gobbo, muito obrigado. Foi de grandíssima ajuda, nem tinha pensado nisso. Não estava chegando a senha e a conexão com o BD não funcionava. Se quiser use este comentário como resposta pq aí irei dar como resolvido. Muito obrigado mesmo. Não imagina como ajudou.